# Mysql database in infopath 2010 form

Tags: list, infopath-data-connections

I have mysql database with table. In this table there are data that i want to show in infopath and i save in sharepoint list. Can you help me how?

Answer (score 0):

**First,** you should be aware of The `SQL Server` is the **only** supported database source in Infopath.

[image]

---

**In your case,** you can achieve your requirements by using the **`Web Service`** as the following:

1. Creating a **`Web Service`** that read data from your data source (**`MySQL`**)

> **Note:** Make sure that the  **`Web Service`** is reachable and accessible inside your SharePoint domain.

2. Consume this **`Web Service`**  in your InfoPath form by adding a new `data connection` as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Can you give me some instruction for creating web service?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362835/web-service-built-in-c-sharp-to-retrieve-data-from-mysql-database, if you need more clarification about web service you can ask this in StackOverflow, please don't forget to Mark this answer as accepted in case it helped you !

Comment: I created web service, bu i have a problem with infopath form. When i open infopath form in preview i receive data from mysql but when i publish form i cannot receive data from mysql